# How to display this in format dd.mm.yyyy?

Tags: javascript

```
alert(end); //Wed Oct 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

How to display this in format dd.mm.yyyy ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [built-in methods on the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype#Methods)

```
alert(end.getDate() + "." + (end.getMonth() + 1) + "." + end.getFullYear());
```

*Note: I'm adding 1 to the month, because javascript returns the month in the range 0-11, with January being 0, February 1, etc.*

*Additional Note: I put parenthesis around that addition, because otherwise it would just do another string concatenation, so July 6, 2013 would become 6-61-2013 without the parenthesis*

Comment: `.getMonth()` goes from 0-11, so `alert(end.getDate() + "." + end.getMonth()+1 + "." + end.getFullYear());`

Comment: I probably want a colon instead of a period? Yeah, maybe, but in the question he said he wanted `dd.mm.yyyy`, so that's what I gave him :)

Comment: Ah, he edited his comment since I replied to it. Good catch, I'll fix my response.

Comment: `.getMonth()` goes from 0-11, so `alert(end.getDate() + "." + (end.getMonth()+1) + "." + end.getFullYear());`   I didn't realize hitting enter on the comment saves it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the additional dependency, you could use Moment.js http://momentjs.com.